# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.cloud.backend.core.CloudEntity

Tags: android, google-cloud-datastore, noclassdeffounderror, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to connect my app with Google Cloud but I get this error.

I'm using the sample project which gives here : https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/android/?hl=es as added to my build path.

This is my code:

```
    CloudEntity newPost = new CloudEntity("Clip");
    newPost.put("clip_url", "Ola k ase, pruebo, o k ase");
    CloudBackend cb = new CloudBackend();
    try {
        cb.insert(newPost);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

instead, I'm not getting errors working with `CloudEntity` in the same package.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Tried also putting the java files on my Project. For example, if my package is com.example.myapp, I'm trying as well using com.example.myapp.CloudEntity

**EDIT 2**

Now my `CloudEntity` works but still having problems with `CloudBackend`

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.cloud.backend.android.mobilebackend.Mobilebackend

Comment: Probably the library you are using to compile your app is not the same there is in the device you are using to test. This happen when you take too long to update google services frameworks library I guess.

Comment: When I run the sample demo, it works instead

Comment: I could see that the sample has the CloudEntity as a project source. Do you have this class in you project source? If yes, is its package `com.google.cloud.backend.core`? I've never used GCS but I'm pretty sure that error is regarding class path/class references

Comment: Yes, I've added as source, also checked on build path, even copied classes to my project...